# Cannot overwrite `users` model once compiled

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, rest, service

```
class UserModel {
    initSchema() {
        const schema = new Schema({
            name: "string",
            email: "string",
            password: "string",
        });
        mongoose.model("users", schema);
    }
    getInstance() {
        this.initSchema();
        return mongoose.model("users");
    }
}

export default UserModel;
```

```
export class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    constructor(model: any) {
        const dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        model = dataAccess.getSchema("users");
        super(model);
    }
}




class DataAccess {
    getSchema = (schema: any) => {
        return mongoose.model(schema);
    }
}
```

> ** The DataAccess class can be assigned to the BaseService for the data manipulation(CRUD)**

> ** I am getting error of the database can not be override when I am
> performing an Operation**

> **Also Confused How to Pass The Name of The UserModel to The
> DataAccess Class Method So I Can Use It In BaseService For The Data Manipulation**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to overwrite your model every time you init it. If you want to use `initSchema` first you need to check if is it registered:

```js
    initSchema() {
        if (mongoose.models.users) {
            return;
        }

        const schema = new Schema({
            name: "string",
            email: "string",
            password: "string",
        });
        mongoose.model("users", schema);
    }
```

Comment: Cannot overwrite `users` model once compiled. Getting the same error